# Cayley’s formula to compute the smallest value of n

Tags: graph-theory

Use Cayley’s formula to compute the smallest value of n for which a labeled,
complete graph with n vertices has more than a million spanning trees.

to do this do you just solve, $n^{n-2} > 1000000$?

I can't seem to solve this if anyone can help?

Comment: This is a matter of finite check. $n=10$ is already big enough (gives you $10^8>10^6$), so you just need to descend (calculate $9^7, 8^6, 7^5$ etc.) until you hit a number less or equal than $10^6$.

Comment: It is also clear that $8^6 < 10^6$, so the $9^7$ vs. $10^6$ comparison is the only one we need to get clever with.

Comment: thanks weren't thinking along those lines at all!

Comment: so  $9^7$ > $10^6$ so the answer is n=8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using algebra, the problem is not too difficult.

Taking logarithms, you want to find the zero of function
$$f(n)=(n-2)\log(n)-k$$ with $k >0$ which implies $n> 2$.
Since $f(n) < n \log(n)$ an upper bound of the solution is given by
$$ n \log(n)=k \implies n > \frac{k}{W(k)}$$ where $W(k)$ is Lambert function.

Using $n_0=\frac{k}{W(k)}$ and performing one single iteration of Halley method, as an *estimate*
$$n_1=n_0+\frac{2 f(n_0) \,f'(n_0)}{f(n_0)\, f''(n_0)-2 f'(n_0)\,f'(n_0)}$$ with
$$f'(n)=1-\frac{2}{n}+\log (n)\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(n)=\frac{n+2}{n^2}$$

Trying  for a few values of $k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.32508 &  2.93018 \\
 2 & 3.36478 &  3.57121 \\
 3 & 4.01581 &  4.11917 \\
 4 & 4.55253 &  4.61541 \\
 5 & 5.03460 &  5.07733 \\
 6 & 5.48307 &  5.51425 \\
 7 & 5.90796 &  5.93184 \\
 8 & 6.31492 &  6.33389 \\
 9 & 6.70758 &  6.72306 \\
 10 & 7.08840 &  7.10131 \\
 11 & 7.45919 &  7.47015 \\
 12 & 7.82130 &  7.83074 \\
 13 & 8.17581 &  8.18404 \\
 14 & 8.52357 &  8.53081 \\
 15 & 8.86526 &  8.87170 \\
 16 & 9.20148 &  9.20724 \\
 17 & 9.53270 &  9.53789 \\
 18 & 9.85934 &  9.86405 \\
 19 & 10.1818 &  10.1861 \\
 20 & 10.5003 &  10.5042
\end{array}
\right)$$
and as usual, you will use for the inequality $\lceil n \rceil$.

For $k=\log(10^6)$ as in the question, this would give $n_1=8.45989$ while the solution is $n=8.46730$ that is to say $n=9$. Checking
$$8^6=262144 < 10^6 \qquad \text{while} \qquad 9^7=4782969 > 10^6$$